# how to create my own namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to create my own namespace of database connectivity in a project and use in .cs file of every .aspx page ??

Comment: ridiculously vague. expand/clarify otherwise it will get closed.

Comment: You want to change the default namespace for all pages in an asp.net web site?

Answer (score 2):

### Current answer

Add your namespace to web.config, system.web section

```
<system.web>
   <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="mynamespace"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages> 
...
```

now **mynamespace** classes are visible on every aspx page.

.

### Old answer (was given on vague question)

Try in solution explorer: 
Project (mouse right button click) -> Properties -> Default Namespace.

Don't forget to change current page(s) namespace (Resharper will help you)